How to calculate sharpe ratio
I have end of month Gold prices, Returns of treasury (in percentages) & end of day NASDAQ index over 20 years. I want to compute risk adjusted returns by finding sharpe ratio. Im confused how do i go about calculating them.

For these 3 assets, i need to bring them to the common scale - so i calculated monthly gold return & equity returns by computing percentage change and then annualize them by multiplying by 12. So i get monthly return %age

then i use the formula of sharpe which is to calculate mean of these returns and divide them by std deviation. For gold and stock market, since i have calculated monthly returns ill multiply the mean by 12 and sigma by sqrt 12 to adjust it to monthly

What is the risk free return to be used. For example, for over 20 year period, the risk free return of any instrument will vary. So do i simply average it out?

I take the entire 20 years as duration, but im realizing that to analyze short term vs long term , i perhaps need to take 1 to N years rolling sharpe ratio and then show how equity & gold is more volatile and smoothens out over a long time range. So to achieve this, do i simply reduce the time range over which i compute sharpe ratio?


My qs:

For #1, is the approach to convert them to annualized returns correct? Whats the ideal way?
For #2- Ive seen some websites using log returns and they dont mention pros/cons of using the same. Is my formulation correct?
Is the rational correct to measure effect of time horizon on sharpe ratio?

TIA

Not sure if I understood your questions perfectly but

Yes, that is fine.
See Discrete returns versus log returns of assets
You should calculate the individual excess returns (monthly returns minus the monthly riskless rate) across all 240 data points, take the average of all of them as the expected excess return to be used in computing the Sharpe. You should repeat for the volatility.
There isn't a right or wrong, you can do both and show the Sharpe ratios across 20 for 1 year or 1 for 20 years.


Q3: i have treasury yield rates for every month for 20 years. So suppose M0=5% and M240=10%
now when im calculating sharpe ratio on 20 year period, what should i take as risk free rate?
Q4: to analyze these investments, is it meaningful to compute sharpe ratio for 1 year windows over 20 years, 2 year windows over 20 years?
taking one single sharpe ratio over the entire 20 years may not give the full picture. Is this understanding correct

Hi @nandonachi I edited my answer to reply to your questions.

thanks! Are there any books or online articles which covers this. I guess i should understand these fundamentals

for #3, i mentioned i have 10 year yield and not monthly returns. So i have yearly yield and riskless rate which is also yearly. so do i still need to adjust these rates to monthly (for this excercise, assume that risk free rate is different than treasury yield)

You said you have treasury yields in your comment every month for 20 years, now you are saying it is a yearly yield, which is it?
